# Cards used for combat

Tags: pathfinder-adventure

I recently got the Pathfinder Adventure Card Game and have played a few games, but have a clarifying question about how many cards can be used for a combat check.

I understand that according to the rules only one of each card type can be used for a particular check, but can a person use a "weapon" and a "spell" that each can be used for a combat check?

So far, I've been playing using only one card type that says "For a combat check...", but I want to make sure that's correct.

Answer (score 8):

The rules can be tricky to find stuff in, but it's there:  page 11, under the heading **Determine Which Die You're Using**, second paragraph:

> [Y]ou may play only 1 card or use only 1 power that changes the skill you are going to use.

So yes, you're playing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes.**
As a matter of fact, as an example, it's how my Seoni maximizes her damage output with her fireballs.
I first discard a card to trigger the power.

I can then do all of the following...

- Reveal the **Sage's Journal**, an Item, to add 1d4, if I'm in combat against a Henchman or Villain.
- Recharge an **Acolyte**, an Ally, to add yet another 1d4 to the check, since it uses my Arcane die.
- Discard a **Blessing of the Gods** to add yet another Arcane die.

It makes her *insanely* powerful, but if I keep doing it, I'll burn through cards... and Seoni's deck size is small enough as it is.

Comment: This answer isn't really correct. The examples you state add **to an existing combat check**, so they're ok. But the OP appears to be asking about combining spells and weapons, which are typically worded as "For your combat check, ...". These effects can not be combined.